# file filter function is not working in multer?

Tags: node.js, multer

I am uploading single file using `multer.fileFilter` function is not working,it is not even being called by `multer.Multer` does not care for file extension whether they are allowed or not and upload all files.
Every thing from frontend  is correct like(`multipart/form-data`, and name of input field is `image`). Here is the my code

This is filefilter functon:

```
const filefilter = (req, file, cb) =>{
    console.log('filefilter executed');
    if (
         file.mimetype === 'image/png' || 
         file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || 
         file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
    ) {
        cb(null, true);
        console.log('image type correct');
    }else {
        console.log('image type incorrect');
        cb('error Message', false);
    }
}
```

and here is how I used it in multer:

```
app.use(multer({storage : fileStorage, filefilter: filefilter }).single('image'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Spelling mistake. In ' filefilter ' key 'f' should be capital, so instead of using:

app.use(multer({storage : fileStorage, filefilter: filefilter }).single('image'));

use following:

app.use(multer({storage : fileStorage, fileFilter: filefilter }).single('image'));